# C# Any chance to detect a "System Setting Change" box progmatically?

Tags: c#, popup, window, detect

I would like to create a program, that detects the appearance, and closes of the following window:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRo7U.jpg
The reason is, because it pops up quite a lot, because we use a lot of usb sticks.
And when it pops up, the default selection is "yes", and if i hit Enter for something different, and the window pops up just before that, the computer restarts..
I already can swith to the window, and send a "n", for No, and close it, but i don't know how to detect if the window pops up.
Any idea?

Comment: I know this comment is probably not going to be useful to you, but upgrading your OS would remove your need to deal with that annoying window.

Comment: Actually i work in a copyshop (with 8 shops in town), and we have a lot of computers, even for self-service printing, so we would need to upgrade almost a hundred computers, maybe we will some time, but so far we're stuck with XP...